# Does the moduli space of genus three curves contain a complete genus two curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces

Inspired by the question

[Does the moduli space of smooth curves of genus g contain an elliptic curve](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103120/does-the-moduli-space-of-smooth-curves-of-genus-g-contain-an-elliptic-curve)

and its amazing answers, I ask (pure out of curiosity) whether the moduli space $M_3$ of (smooth projective connected) curves of genus $3$ contains a (smooth projective connected) curve of genus $2$.

The existence of such a genus two curve is (Edit: **stronger**) than the existence of a surface $S$, a genus two curve $C$ and a smooth projective non-isotrivial morphism $S\to C$ whose fibres are genus three curves.

If the answer is positive, how explicit can our answer be made? I'm already aware of the fact that $M_g$ contains a complete curve for all $g\geq 3$. For instance, in the  paper by Chris Zaal

http://dare.uva.nl/document/38546

many curves of some genus (I think 513) are shown to embed into $M_3$.

Of course, by Shafarevich' conjecture, if $K(C)$ denotes the function field of $C$, there are only finitely many non-isotrivial $K(C)$-isomorphism classes of genus three curves over $K(C)$ with good reduction over $C$. I'm asking whether there exists some genus two curve $C$ such that there exists a genus three curve over $K(C)$ with good reduction over $C$.

**Edit:** the arithmetic analogue also has a negative answer.

The latter (**weaker**) phrasing of my question allows us to formulate an arithmetic analogue of the above question. (I know that I'm considering function fields over $\mathbf{C}$ and that some of you might argue function fields over $\mathbf{F}_p$ are a better analogue of number fields.) This arithmetic analogue reads as follows. There exists a number field of "genus two" such that there exist a genus three  curve over $K$ with good reduction over the ring of integers of $K$. Here a number field of "genus two"  should be a number field of absolute discriminant $e^2$. I'll take this to mean discriminant at most $8$.

**Arithmetic analogue. (Abrashkin-Fontaine)** There do not exist non-zero smooth abelian schemes over the ring of integers of a number field of absolute discriminant at most 8.

There are many related questions I'd also like to ask. For example, what is the minimal $g$ such that $M_g$ contains a genus two curve? Or, what is the minimal $g$ such that $M_3$ contains a genus $g$ curve? And, finally, is there an example of a complete curve in $M_g$ which is defined over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$? (Edit: The answer to the last question is positive. This is explained in the comments below.)

Comment: [In the penultimate paragraph, perhaps instead of $M_3(C)$, which I think would be the notation for all morphisms from $C$ to $M_3$ including constants, you should use another notation?]

Comment: "The existence of such a genus two curve is equivalent to the existence of a surface $S$, a genus two curve $C$ and a smooth projective morphism $S \to C$ whose fibres are genus three curves". This is not completely correct: you must require that the fibration $f \colon S \to C$ is *not isotrivial*, otherwise you can always take $S=C \times F$, where $C$ has genus $2$ and $F$ has genus $3$ (needless to say, the image of such a $S$ in $M_3$ is a point).   

Comment: Setting aside the fact that $M_g$ is a stack and not a scheme, non-isotriviality is also too weak: it only says that the map from $C$ to the stack is non-constant, not that it is a closed immersion (or even just injective on geometric points). Also, concerning the question at the very end, by "spreading out and specialization" we see that there are complete curves of a given genus inside $M_g$ over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ if this holds over one algebraically closed field of char. 0 (such as $\mathbf{C}$), or maybe "an example" meant to include "explicit"?

Comment: In general a map $C$ to $M_3$ does come from a family of curves on $C$.

Comment: @xbnv. Thank you. That answers my last question. 

Comment: Doublecheck the question you link to! $M_2$ does not contain any complete curves.

Comment: But you're claiming that you're "already aware of the fact that $M_g$ contains a complete curve for all $g \geq 2$". Should that be $>$ instead of $\geq$ then?

Comment: Yeah that's a typo. My apologies. I didn't notice that.

Comment: We can divide $M_3$ into the hyperelliptic and plane quartic curves.  The first thing I'd try to work out is whether such a map can be entirely hyperelliptic, can be entirely plane quartic, or must intersect both domains. Does anyone know?

Comment: @Will Sawin. The locus of hyperelliptic curves (or more generally cyclic covers of prime degree in $M_g$) is affine. This is a result of Gonzalez Diez (1991); see "Loci of curves which are prime Galois coverings of P^1". Probably the result for hyperelliptic curves is more classical.

Comment: @Will Sawin (continued). So there is no complete curve contained in the locus of hyperelliptic curves of $M_3$. Moreover, the generic fibre of $S\to C$ has to be a smooth quartic. In fact, if it were hyperelliptic, all fibres would be hyperelliptic because $S\to C$ is smooth.

Comment: Another way to see that there exist examples over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ is that the compactification of $M_g$ with small boundary that is used to construct complete curves in $M_g$ is defined over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ (it is the image of $\bar{M}_g$ in the Satake compactification of $A_g$ by the Torelli morphism).

Comment: @Ariyan. Yes, the result for hyperelliptic curves is very classical. There is an isomorphism $H_g \cong M_{0,2g+2}/\mathbb{S}_{2g+2}$, and $M_{0,n}$ is obviously affine (it is the complement of an arrangement of hyperplanes in $\mathbb{A}^{n-3}$).

Comment: For the unenlightened among us, where does this surface come from?

Comment: The stack $M_g$ behaves like a classifying space. It has a bundle of genus $g$ curves. THus, any map $C \to M_g$ induces the pullback of that bundle, which is a surface.

Comment: @Will. Ah, I see.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There does not exist a map of a smooth complete genus 2 curve to $M_3$.

Such a map would give rise to a surface $S$ (of general type) which violates the Bogomolov-Miyaoka-Yau inequality $c_1(S)^2 \leq 3c_2(S)$. This inequality is equivalent to $3\sigma (S) \leq e(S)$ where $\sigma$ and $e$ are the signature and topological euler characteristic of the surface. The euler characteristic of this surface is 8 (since it is multiplicative for fiber bundles) and by the index theorem, the signature is given by 4 times the integral of $\lambda_1$ over the curve in $M_3$. Since $\lambda_1$ is ample on $M_3$, $\sigma$ must be positive and divisible by 4.

This argument is due to Dieter Kotschick in his paper "Signatures, Monopoles, and Mapping Class Groups" (MRL vol 5, 1998).

Comment: Nice.$ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Thank you very much. With the purpose of clarifying certain parts for myself I added some remarks to your answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Who actually answered? Since the question is CW (for reasons that escape me) the original poster is not visible.

Comment: A Kodaira fibration (a family of curves corresponding to a nonconstant map $B \to M_g$) always has general type.

Comment: Jim Bryan answered the question and I don't know why the question became CW. 

Comment: Any MO question automatically becomes CW after sufficiently many edits. I do not really understand this feature. 

Comment: I think Jim made it CW at the very beginning though.

Comment: I did not make it a CW. I just answered the question.

Comment: It became CW because the question became CW after 10 revisions :)

Comment: @Ariyan: for some value of "famous."

Comment: @Jim and @J.C. I am even more confused. I assume that this answer is due to @Jim. But who asked the question?

Comment: This is a very nice argument ! However, if I understand well, it is not strong enough to answer the following question : does there exist a non-isotrivial family of smooth curves over a genus $2$ curve ? More generally, what is the smallest genus of a curve that carries a non-isotrivial family of smooth curves ?

Comment: @Olivier : There does indeed exist a genus 2 curve with a non-isotrivial family over it. Moreover, this is the minimal genus with this property. Ron Donagi and I proved that in our Geometry and Topology paper:  http://www.msp.warwick.ac.uk/gt/2002/06/gt-2002-06-003p.pdf

Comment: @Jim : Thanks for the reference, I did not know your paper. These constructions are very nice indeed !